# Netbeans 7.2.1 broken reference : dist.jar (when coding on a JavaFX file)

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to learn JavaFX with reading some tutorials however, I couldn't even implement the "helloworld" application. The NetBeans said:

> Error: Could not find or load main class helloworld.NewFXMain
>   Java Result: 1

and then when I checked Properties-->Libraries-->Run part there is a warning which says

> Broken reference : dist.jar

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try to clean and build the project again.

Answer (score 4):

when you create a new project in java fx and want to run the project for demo then this error occur .
     you can try it given below:-
 1.right click on project.
  then click on clean and build.
its running your project in netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

Before running, try "clean and Build Project" option.

- Menu->Run->Clean and Build Project

then run your project.
It worked for me.