# JavaFX Error with Netbeans Standard FXML application - Nullpointer for .fxml file

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, javafx

When I create a new Netbeans Projekt (JavaFX FXML Application) with application class I receive a template as usual (one .fxml, one controller class and the main application). When I try to run this I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2825)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2809)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2795)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2782)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2771)
    at volltextsuche.Volltextsuche.start(Volltextsuche.java:25)
    [...]
```

This is my start() method:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    URL url = getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml");
    System.out.println(url == null);
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

and somehow the URL is null. Line 25 is the `Parent root = [...]` part. The .fxml document has the exact same name as the Strings tell and is in the same package as the main application class. I didn't change anything, just the null check for the URL. I googled for a long time, but I couldn't find anything regarding this error.

- JDK 8.0_45
- Netbeans 8.0.2
- Win 8.1 x64

[image: IDE with project]

Comment: Is the FXML file in the same package as the `Application` class whose code you showed?

Comment: Yes it is. Sadly the URL is instantly null and I'm not able to print the path...

Comment: Can you see if the FXML is deployed along with the class files to wherever it is that Netbeans deploys its class files? (I'm not a NetBeans user, but I understand that sometimes it needs coercing to deploy resources other than class files from the source folders.)

Comment: Good hint, for some reason the log says `Compiling 1 source file to D:\NetbeansProjects\Volltextsuche\build\classes` and just the main application file got compiled. Not even the controller class. But I really have no clue why.

Comment: I compiled the controller manually, but the error stays the same (I can't compile the .fxml).

Comment: Got it working by copying the .fxml manually into the `\build\classes\volltextsuche` folder where the compiled class files are located, but that really is an ugly workaround I guess... Somethings wrong with the compiler apparently.

Comment: If you compile it manually, then it will compile the Java source code you specify and any explicit dependencies. As you point out, an FXML file is not compiled anyway, so that will not be automatically copied to the destination. There is no explicit dependency on the controller class: the controller is loaded by reflection based on (typically) attributes in the FXML file, so the compiler is never going to be aware of that dependency. If you let Netbeans build the project instead of compiling "by hand", it should be able to do the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the error, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446779/netbeans-7-2-1-broken-reference-dist-jar-when-coding-on-a-javafx-file). The error is differnent but the solution is the same. I found a broken reference to dist.jar in my project settings. As the answered question in the link states I had to `CLEAN and build` the project for the first build. The broken reference got fixed by that. I deleted all already compiled files and now the compiler does everything needed and compiles the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a temporary solution that works.

First copy the resource to the same directory as src folder.

So if your src folder path is C:app/src , then copy all resources to C :app

Run the application again.